# "Enable Mouse Keys" option in Accessibility not working

Tags: macos, keyboard, mouse, trackpad, productivity

I am trying to control the trackpad of my macbook via keyboard but the "Enable Mouse Keys" option in Accessibility does not enable the mouse control which should be the 789UIOJKL keys.

What am I doing wrong?

OS: Big Sur
Machine: Macbook Air M1

I have Alfred, Keyboard Maestro and Karabiner Elements installed but as far as I know the relevant keys should not be affected by any macros. Any way to debug this?

Comment: Do you have the 'tap Opt 5 times' enabled? Does it show on screen as you switch? https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrXwo.jpg [Remote chance… do you have an extended keyboard attached?]

Comment: Yes, I have it enabled and the sound plays when I press it but the 789UIOJKL keys do still not move the mouse.

Comment: & the extended keyboard…?

Comment: extended keyboard?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeCJk.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and Karabiner Elements seems guilty. Mouse Keys started working after turning Karabiner Elements off.